# How to create Vue.Js component dynamically - modal messagebox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I am working in asp.net project with VueJs. I would like to create own message box depends on modal. My problem is to with each `$emit` call create component, show message box and in `hideModal` function destroy component.

Actually, when I will call many times in for loop `this.$root.$emit('show-message', this.showMessage);` - component shows just one time. I want to show every `messageBox`, not only the first one.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  Vue.component('message-box', {
    props: {},
    data: function() {
      return {
        messageTitle: '',
        messageBody: '',
        visible: false,
      }
    },
    template: `<b-modal centered v-model="visible">
                <template slot="modal-header">
                    {{messageTitle}}
                </template>
                <div class="d-block text-center">
                    {{messageBody}}
                </div>
                <template slot="modal-footer">
                    <b-button class="mt-3" variant="outline-info" block v-on:click="hideModal()">Ok</b-button>         
                </template>
               </b-modal>`,
    created: function() {
      this.$root.$on('show-message', this.showMessage)
    },
    beforeDestroy: function() {
      EventBus.$off('show-message', this.showMessage)
    },
    methods: {
      showModal() {
        this.visible = true
      },
      hideModal() {
        this.visible = false
      },
      close: function(index) {
        this.alerts.splice(index, 1)
      },
      showMessage: function(title, message) {
        this.messageTitle = title
        this.messageBody = message
        this.showModal()
      },
    },
  })
})()
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating your `<message-box>`? If you want to have multiple message boxes on the screen at once, then your component should support displaying multiple messages (and you keep track of each message in an array), or you need to instantiate multiple `<message-box>` components for each message (it would be managed by the parent component instead of the message box itself).

Comment: You are right, but the problem for me is exactly that I do not know how to instantiate multiple ```<message-box>``` in parent - but thanks, You gave me a trivial solution using the array.

Comment: You can render multiple using `v-for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly, this is not exactly the solution I was looking for. Still, it solves my problem.

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    Vue.component('message-box', {
        props: {
        },
        data: function () {
            return {
                messages: [],
                actualMessage: {},
                visible: false
            };
        },
        template:
            `<b-modal centered v-model="visible">
                <template slot="modal-header" v-if="actualMessage">
                     {{actualMessage.messageTitle}}
                </template>
                <div class="d-block text-center" v-if="actualMessage">
                    {{actualMessage.messageBody}}
                </div>
                <template slot="modal-footer">
                    <b-button class="mt-3" variant="outline-info" block v-on:click="hideModal()">Ok</b-button>         
        </template>
        </b-modal>`,
        created: function () {
            this.$root.$on('show-message', this.showMessage);
        },
        beforeDestroy: function () {
            EventBus.$off('show-message', this.showMessage);
        },
        methods: {
            showModal() {
                this.actualMessage = this.messages[0];
                this.visible = true;
            },
            hideModal() {
                this.visible = false;
                this.messages.splice(0, 1);
                if (this.messages.length > 0) {
                    var vm = this;
                    setTimeout(function () { vm.showModal(); }, 500);
                }
            },
            showMessage: function (title, message) {
                this.messages.push({ messageTitle: title, messageBody: message });
                if (!this.visible)
                    this.showModal();
            }
        }
    });
})();
```